# Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException in React Native

Tags: react-native, scrollview

Below is the error I got in the firebase crashlytics of my app.

**ERROR: UIScrollView does not support multiple observers implementing _scrollViewWillEndDraggingWithVelocity:targetContentOffset:**

I've googled to find the solution, but couldn't. Does anyone has an idea of this? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Below is the stack trace of the crash

Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x119180 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x59f8 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x3288c +[_CFXNotificationTokenRegistration keyCallbacks]
3  Foundation                     0x8ab38 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  UIKitCore                      0xcefe0c -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _addScrollViewScrollObserver:]
5  UIKitCore                      0x27f35c -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:]
6  UIKitCore                      0x2830d4 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:]
7  UIKitCore                      0x27dda4 -[UINavigationController _layoutTopViewController]
8  UIKitCore                      0x27d068 -[UINavigationController _updateBarsForCurrentInterfaceOrientationAndForceBarLayout:]
9  UIKitCore                      0x33fe9c -[_UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator _applyBlocks:releaseBlocks:]
10 UIKitCore                      0x33c490 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext __runAlongsideAnimations]
11 UIKitCore                      0xd4825c +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:]
12 UIKitCore                      0xd4879c +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:]
13 UIKitCore                      0x353314 __58-[_UIWindowRotationAnimationController animateTransition:]_block_invoke_2
14 UIKitCore                      0xd4c87c +[UIView(Internal) _performBlockDelayingTriggeringResponderEvents:]
15 UIKitCore                      0x3530a4 __58-[_UIWindowRotationAnimationController animateTransition:]_block_invoke
16 UIKitCore                      0x352fa0 -[_UIWindowRotationAnimationController animateTransition:]
17 UIKitCore                      0x8f96c0 -[UIWindow _rotateToBounds:withAnimator:transitionContext:]
18 UIKitCore                      0x8fbe24 -[UIWindow _rotateWindowToOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:skipCallbacks:]
19 UIKitCore                      0x8fc4d8 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:]
20 UIKitCore                      0x8fb8d8 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:]
21 UIKitCore                      0x8fa584 __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke
22 UIKitCore                      0x8fa488 -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]
23 UIKitCore                      0x182fe0 -[_UICanvasMetricsCalculator updateMetricsOnWindows:animated:]
24 UIKitCore                      0x187990 -[_UICanvas _computeMetrics:]
25 UIKitCore                      0xd468f0 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:]
26 UIKitCore                      0x1864a8 -[_UICanvas _performActions:withOverrideSettings:]
27 UIKitCore                      0x8c7b0c -[UIApplication _createSnapshotContextForScene:withName:performLayoutWithSettings:]
28 UIKitCore                      0x8c92f0 __65-[UIApplication _performSnapshotsWithAction:forScene:completion:]_block_invoke_2
29 FrontBoardServices             0x43768 -[FBSSceneSnapshotAction _executeNextRequest]
30 FrontBoardServices             0x437b8 -[FBSSceneSnapshotAction _executeNextRequest]
31 FrontBoardServices             0x43358 -[FBSSceneSnapshotAction executeRequestsWithHandler:completionHandler:expirationHandler:]
32 UIKitCore                      0x8c9220 __65-[UIApplication _performSnapshotsWithAction:forScene:completion:]_block_invoke
33 UIKitCore                      0x8c8848 -[UIApplication _beginSnapshotSessionForScene:withSnapshotBlock:]
34 UIKitCore                      0x8c8f74 -[UIApplication _performSnapshotsWithAction:forScene:completion:]
35 UIKitCore                      0x8c8e40 -[UIApplication _handleSnapshotAction:forScene:completion:]
36 UIKitCore                      0x8c4724 __71-[UIApplication _handleSnapshotAction:forScene:deactivationCompletion:]_block_invoke
37 UIKitCore                      0x8c4540 -[UIApplication _handleSnapshotAction:forScene:deactivationCompletion:]
38 UIKitCore                      0x17ff58 __98-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability deactivateEventsOnly:withContext:forceExit:completion:]_block_invoke.261
39 UIKitCore                      0x8c80ac _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks
40 UIKitCore                      0x8b6bfc _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks
41 UIKitCore                      0x8e3a6c _afterCACommitHandler
42 CoreFoundation                 0xaa4fc **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION**
43 CoreFoundation                 0xa5224 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
44 CoreFoundation                 0xa57a0 __CFRunLoopRun
45 CoreFoundation                 0xa4fb4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
46 GraphicsServices               0xa79c GSEventRunModal